# Problem understanding proof that $e^a+e^b \geq e^{a+b}$

Tags: exponential-function

The answer is shown here by Rajada:

[Proof for which exponent is greater](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449450/proof-for-which-exponent-is-greater/1449459#1449459])

q1.) His solution seems nice but I can't understand how he gets to the second line from the first? (I understand the first line)

$$\frac{(e^a + e^b)}{2} \geq e^{\frac{(a+b)}{2}}\text{ (Using A.M.-G.M. inequality.)}$$
$$(e^a + e^b) > e^{\frac{(a+b+1)}{2}}\text{ (Using $4>e$).}$$

Can someone please explain.

Also his solution only applies to:

$$(e^a + e^b)> e^{(a+b+1)} \text{ when, }a+b+1 \leq 0.$$

q2.) Is it safe to assume that the direction of the inequality reverses when $\text{ when, }a+b+1 \geq 0.$

Comment: SInce $4>e$, therefore, $2>e^{1/2}$ and so $(e^a+e^b)>\exp{[(a+b)/2+1/2]}$

Comment: $e^a+e^b\ge 2e^{\frac{a+b}{2}}=4^{1/2}e^{\frac{a+b}{2}}>e^{1/2}e^{\frac{a+b}{2}}=e^{\frac{a+b+1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

q1: Multiply the left-hand side by $2$ and the right-hand side by $e^{1/2}$. Since $2>e^{1/2}$ this preserves the inequality.

q2: No, because there's some slack in the preceding steps. For example the original inequality is always true when one of $a$ and $b$ is $0$, no matter what the other one is.

Comment: OK Q1 clearer now but why does the inequality become strict?

Comment: @Bazman: Because $2$ is _strictly_ larger than $e^{1/2}$.

Comment: for Q2 Is there a more general solution that you can point me too?

Comment: @Bazman: I doubt there is any _exact_ condition that is appreciably nicer than the inequality itself.

Comment: You are probably correct but I am asked to prove the statement shown in the first line is it acceptable to state that this is the case because of the AM-GM theorem?

Comment: @Bazman: On further thought, it is possible to simplify _slightly_. I have added an answer to the original question.